# apache uima ruta - non english sentence processing

Tags: apache, uima, ruta

I tested RUTA script with two different languages(English, Korean).
I wanted to get same result that is splitted by word. but Korean sentence was not splitted by word.

Script :
         DECLARE Last1;
         W {-> Last1};

Document : "This is a sample."

Result :
   This ,
   is ,
   a ,
   sample

Document : "이것은 샘플입니다."
Result :
         "" (nothing)

The result that I want to get :
           이것은 , 샘플입니다

the result is nothing. I want to know how can I detect non-english word as a word in Ruta.

I hope your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved using 'split'.

Sentence{-> SPLIT(SPACE)};

(apache uima rota-core 2.6.1)

anyway, I want to know how to separate the unicode words using reserved keyword "W".

Comment: Ask unicode problem as different Question with Sample input and Expected result.